# when ng-model value rounding using number getting "ngModel:nonassign"?

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-model=="value | number : 2" but am getting below error in console.

```
Error: [ngModel:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ngModel/nonassign?p0=sumatoriaDeCuotas%20%7C%20number%20%3A%202&p1=%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20ng-model%3D<input type="text" ng-model="sumatoriaDeCuotas | number : 2" class="no-margin resumedatotabletd1 ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-class="{'errorhilight': sumatoriaDeCuotas < 0}" ng-disabled="mySwitch" disabled="disabled">umatoriaDeCuotas%20%7C%20number%20%3A%202%22%class%3D%22no-margin%20resumedatotabletd1%20ng-pristine%20ng-untouched%20ng-valid%22%20ng-class%3D%22%7B'errorhilight'%3A%sumatoriaDeCuotas%20%3C%200%7D%22%20ng-disabled%3D%22mySwitch%22%20disabled%3D%disabled%22%3E
    at http://localhost:8082/js/commons/angular.min.js:6:412
    at Pg.$$setOptions (http://localhost:8082/js/commons/angular.min.js:282:81)
    at Object.pre (http://localhost:8082/js/commons/angular.min.js:289:300)
    at http://localhost:8082//js/commons/angular.min.js:16:71
    at la (http://localhost:8082/js/commons/angular.min.js:81:90)
    at p (http://localhost:8082/js/commons/angular.min.js:66:149)
    at g (http://localhost:8082/js/commons/angular.min.js:58:481)
    at g (http://localhost:8082/js/commons/angular.min.js:58:498)
    at g (http://localhost:8082/js/commons/angular.min.js:58:498)
    at g (http://localhost:8082/js/commons/angular.min.js:58:498)
```

Answer (score 1):

To cut it short - you can't use filters in `ng-model` expressions. Filters are for output formatting while `ng-model` has to do with input. `ng-model` expressions should always be as a normal left part of an assign expression. If your expression is something else it will fail. So whenever you write `ng-model="expression"` think of it like `expression = $modelValue`. In your case it is `value | number:2 = $modelValue`. Which makes little sense.